# Mail app freezes after opening?

Tags: macos, mail.app, macbook-pro

Ok, let me start by saying that I just started using a Mac about two months ago.

Yesterday I was doing something that kicked off about 500 emails to my email account.  When I tried to open my mail app, it pops up and then the cursor turns to a beachball that spins.  After this I have to do a force quit to get out.

I tried looking at the logs in the console, but it appears to be a giant stack trace that is pretty much meaningless to me.  Any suggestions on where to start to get this resolved?

Below is the first little chunk under "User Diagnostic Reports" (it goes on for quite a while after that):

> Process:         Mail [242] Path:
>   /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail Identifier:
>   com.apple.mail Version:         5.3 (1283) Build Info:
>   Mail-1283000000000000~1 Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent
>   Process:  launchd [219]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-12-04 12:33:14.223 -0800 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.5 (11G63) Report Version:  9
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000
>
> VM Regions Near 0:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 0000000107e31000-00000001081e5000 [ 3792K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
>
> Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name:
>   isKindOfClass: objc[242]: garbage collection is OFF
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff87ee5110 objc_msgSend_vtable4
>   + 16 1   com.apple.AppKit                 0x00007fff88d94c16 -[NSView _endEditingIfFirstResponderIsASubview] + 92 2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88d948aa -[NSView removeFromSuperview] + 128 3
>   com.apple.mail                    0x0000000107e8a112 0x107e31000 + 364818
>   4   com.apple.mail                    0x0000000107e887d1 0x107e31000 +
>   358353 5   com.apple.mail                 0x0000000107eafbec
>   0x107e31000 + 519148 6   com.apple.mail
>     0x0000000107eafb9d 0x107e31000 + 519069 7   com.apple.mail
>     0x0000000107eaf699 0x107e31000 + 517785 8   com.apple.Foundation
>     0x00007fff8b560ae1 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 116 9
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8b5276b4
>   -[**NSOperationInternal start] + 705 10  com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8b53a912 _**_NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 + 124 11 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff89f26a82
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18 12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89f288f2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 308 13 
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff81457e7c __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1724 14  com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff81457486
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230 15  com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff883ff2bf RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277 16 
>   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff8840656d
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355 17  com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff884063fa BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62 18 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff88c82779 _DPSNextEvent + 659
>   19  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff88c8207d -[NSApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135 20 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff88c7e9b9 -[NSApplication run]
>   + 470 21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88efaeac NSApplicationMain + 867 22  com.apple.mail
>     0x0000000107f09300 0x107e31000 + 885504

Comment: What steps have you taken to try and resolve the issue to date?

Comment: Posted this question.  And forced quit/restarted about a million times

Comment: So no other Internet based searches beyond this site?

Comment: Did some searching around as well.  That's how I found the console thing with the info I posted.  But didn't find anything that suggested any actions I could take to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the email account and re-adding it.  Once I did that everything fired right up.

Hope this helps someone...